# How to receive a RabbitMQ Event with Serverless + Golang

Tags: go, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Using the serverless framework + Go, how should I receive a RabbitMQ Event e retrieve it's body content? I've tried with the SQS Event type but it comes empty.

```
import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

// Handler is our lambda handler invoked by the `lambda.Start` function call
func Handler(ctx context.Context, sqsEvent events.SQSEvent) error {
    log.Println("SQS Event", sqsEvent)
    for _, v := range sqsEvent.Records {
        log.Println(v.Body)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

Comment: is the rabbitmq event sent directly to the lambda without other proxies? have you tried with `events.RabbitMQEvent`?